# How to access videos from Photo Album and play them?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

Following code used to save videos to photo Album.

```
else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
    {

        NSString *sourcePath = [[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"]relativePath]; 
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(sourcePath,nil,nil,nil);
    }
```

If it is video i want to play it if it is image i want to display it.

Help Me.

Answer (score 1):

with the code check if is image or video :

```
    NSString *mediaType1 = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    NSLog(@"mediaType : %@",mediaType1);

    if ([mediaType1 isEqualToString:@"public.image"])
    {
        //Show Image
}
else
{
    //show Video
}
```

To Play the video check the [URL](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/mediaplayer-framework_mpmovieplayercontroller_ios4/).

**EDIT:**

```
        NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"IMG_0017" ofType:@"MOV"];
        NSLog(@"moviePath : %@",moviePath);
     //   NSURL *movieURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];

        NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strValURL];
        NSLog(@"movieURL : %@",movieURL);
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] doubleValue] >= 3.2)
        {
            NSLog(@"> 3.2");
            MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
            if (mp)
            {
                [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
                mp.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
                [mp.moviePlayer play];
                [mp release];
            }
        }
        else if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] doubleValue] < 3.2)
        {
            NSLog(@"< 3.2");
            theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: movieURL];
            theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
             addObserver: self
             selector: @selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)
             name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
             object: theMovie];
            [theMovie play];
        }

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:moviePlayer];
    [moviePlayer release];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}

- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification 
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:player];
    [player autorelease];
}
```

Comment: i Know how to check it.. i want if it is video how to play it

Comment: for that I have given the URL. Check it.

Answer (score 1):

In your `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` method, you can get the url of the video and play it:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController;

if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"])
{
    NSURL *aURL    = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];//get the url
    // and init the video player using this url
    _moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:aURL];
    [self.view _moviePlayerController.view];
    _moviePlayerController.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
    _moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    [_moviePlayerController play];
}
```

Of course, you'll have to import the `MediaPlayer.framework`

**EDIT:** A majority of Cocoa projects now use `arc`, so the above code would require you retain the `MPMoviePlayerController` instance yourself (as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058138/why-wont-my-mpmovieplayercontroller-play)).

Comment: @Shreedhar I've done this in the `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` method.

Comment: @c0d3Junk13 Please be specific. What part doesn't work? Did you try debugging it?

Comment: In my scenario, I'm trying to play a recently captured and saved video  (to photos album) using the camera (file name is captured.mov or something like that) and even if the URL that is getting passed is correct, it is not playing the video... I'm debugging it myself right now. If I pass a local video (.mp4) that is in the project it works.

Comment: Ok, my problem was related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058138/why-wont-my-mpmovieplayercontroller-play The player was not being retained... I'll take off the down mark on your answer if you can make an edit :(

Comment: Ah, I see! Apparently, I had fixed a similar problem a long time back myself simply by retaining the player! I've edited the answer to reflect the case with `arc`.

Comment: Thanks, at least its a more complete answer now, you got my up-vote for that :)