# How to get videos from photo album and play

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Please help me with an example of getting videos from photo album and play.

Following code is not working

```
NSURL *URL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
  MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:aurl];
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
        moviePlayerController.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
        moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
        [moviePlayerController play];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access videos from Photo Album and play them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006312/how-to-access-videos-from-photo-album-and-play-them)

Answer (score 1):

```
 // Choose video from library                   
                        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                        imagePicker.delegate = self;
                        imagePicker.mediaTypes =
                        [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
                         imagePicker.sourceType];
                        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                        [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
                        [imagePicker release];
```

//Get Video

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){
        NSLog(@"found an image");
    }
    else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"]){
        NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        NSLog(@"found a video");
        NSData *webData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
       }

}
```

//Play Video

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *movie = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self.view addSubview:movie.view];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movie];
[movie release];
```

Comment: okay I added code for playing the video. I copied it from one of my own apps, so I know it works

Comment: try adding this line "[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated: moviePlayerController];"