# Why won't my MPMoviePlayerController play?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to get a basic .mov video file to play using the code below, but when the button I have assigned the action is pressed, the only thing that shows up is the black frame, but no video is played. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
@implementation SRViewController

-(IBAction)playMovie{
    NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                     pathForResource:@"OntheTitle" ofType:@"mov"];
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                                       initWithContentURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];

    // Play Partial Screen
    player.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 720, 480);
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];

    // Play Movie
    [player play];
}

@end
```

Comment: does it show a blank black screen?

Answer (score 13):

Assumed precondition: **your project is using ARC**.

Your `MPMoviePlayerController` instance is local only and ARC has no way of telling that you need to retain that instance. As the controller is not retained by its view, the result is that your `MPMoviePlayerController` instance will be released directly after the execution of your `playMovie` method execution.

To fix that issue, simply add a property for the player instance to your `SRViewController` class and assign the instance towards that property.

Header:

```
@instance SRViewController

   [...]

   @property (nonatomic,strong) MPMoviePlayerController *player;

   [...]

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation SRViewController

   [...]

    -(IBAction)playMovie
    {
        NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                         pathForResource:@"OntheTitle" ofType:@"mov"];
        self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                                           initWithContentURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];

        // Play Partial Screen
        self.player.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 720, 480);
        [self.view addSubview:self.player.view];

        // Play Movie
        [self.player play];
    }

    [...]

@end
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! I got the video to load now, but when it plays, it only plays audio. I'm not sure what the problem is, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: OK...I solved the problem...the codec of the video was just wrong.

Comment: i hate when a question get answered but the creator just goes away not giving points or anything