# Declaring a property

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to declare a property

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController*player;
}


@end
```

I receive a red warning sign when i click on it, it reads;

a parameter list without types is only allowed in function definition

Answer (score 0):

properties are outside of braces

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{ 
   // here is for ivars only
   id _something;
}
// properties and methods
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController*player;

@end
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I've been trying to get this code to work for the past 24 hours it finally works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604509/play-video-in-view-controller using the update here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058138/why-wont-my-mpmovieplayercontroller-play?rq=1